# Leaf Curling in Japanese Loquat

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, diseases, leaves, fruit-trees

Why does the deformation/curling (shown by the red circles) happen for the leaves of my Japanese loquat?
It has been a few days since I bought this tree, and the young leaves on the crown have risen in my growth room.

- Temperature: ~24 °C
- Humidity: ~70%
- Light: 18 Hours LED (No Sunlight)

[image]

Comment: I think its just part of the serrated edges. It looks healthy.

Comment: Can I know why isn't it getting full sunlight? Fruit trees especially ones native to tropics require sunlight.

Comment: Also the cause curling of newer leaves is the lack of water. Is it getting enough water to compensate for transpiration?

Comment: Because a big wall has covered all the windows of my house. Also, I live in a city with cold, dry winters, and hot, dry summers. I try to have regular watering for my plants, but I think watering can be the case.